# Using a Tkinter script to launch another script

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner in code and I'd like to create an interface to make my work easier.

I wanted to create a tkinter interface to request an API in order to download data according to some parameters.

I'd like to do two different scripts because I want to learn how to do it on a simple object and apply it to other opportunities.

**My scripts works when I run them individually, but I can't link them. I have no errors, but nothing happens**. When I run the tkinter script, nothing happens in the second one...I use notebook jupyter. My Tkinter script is in .ipynb format and the second one, designed to process the request, is in .py format.

## My first script using tkinter in .ipynb format :

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

def lancer_script():
    # Récupérer la valeur saisie par l'utilisateur pour territory
    territory = entry_departement.get()
    activity = entry_activity.get()

    # Vérifier si territory est vide
    if not territory:
        # Si territory est vide, afficher un message d'erreur ou faire quelque chose d'autre
        label_result.config(text="Veuillez saisir une valeur pour le département.")
    elif not activity:
        # Si territory est vide, afficher un message d'erreur ou faire quelque chose d'autre
        label_result.config(text="Veuillez saisir une valeur pour l'activité.")
    else:
        # Si territory n'est pas vide, exécuter votre autre script Python (au format .py)
        subprocess.run(['python', 'pynsee.py',
                        f'--territory={territory}',
                        f'--activity={activity}'])

# Créer une première fenêtre
window = Tk()

# Personnaliser la fenêtre
window.title("Sirene Data Downloader")
window.minsize(480, 200)
font_title = ("Montserrat", 15)
font_subtitle = ("Montserrat", 10)

# Ajouter un titre
label_title = Label(window, text="Création de listes d'entreprises sur-mesure", font=font_title)
label_title.pack()

# Créer l'étiquette et l'entrée pour le département
label_activity = Label(window, text="Code d'activité:", font= font_subtitle)
label_activity.pack()

entry_activity = Entry(window)
entry_activity.pack()

# Créer l'étiquette et l'entrée pour le département
label_departement = Label(window, text="Code département:", font = font_subtitle)
label_departement.pack()

entry_departement = Entry(window)
entry_departement.pack()

# Créer le bouton de requête
button_query = Button(window, text="Effectuer la requête", font = font_subtitle, command=lancer_script)
button_query.pack()

# Créer l'étiquette pour afficher le résultat ou les messages
label_result = Label(window, text="")
label_result.pack()

# On crée notre fenêtre et on l'affiche
window.mainloop()
```

## My second script to request API in .py format :

```
import os
import platform
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

print("Script started.")  # Message pour indiquer le début du script

# Création des listes comme paramètre des requêtes
print("Processing territory and activity...")  # Message pour indiquer le traitement des paramètres
territory = "|".join([dep + "*" for dep in territory])
activity = r"|".join(activity)

# Set up du token
print("Setting up the token...")  # Message pour indiquer la mise en place du token
from pynsee.utils.init_conn import init_conn
init_conn(insee_key="key", insee_secret="secret")

# Nettoyage du cache des datas
print("Cleaning cache...")  # Message pour indiquer le nettoyage du cache
from pynsee.utils import clear_all_cache; clear_all_cache()

# On importe une liste de toutes les colonnes utiles pour effectuer des requêtes avec search_sirene
print("Searching Sirene data...")  # Message pour indiquer la recherche des données Sirene
from pynsee.sirene import search_sirene

# Obtention des données sur les entreprises à partir de critères sur les variables
print("Getting data from Sirene...")  # Message pour indiquer l'obtention des données Sirene
export = search_sirene(variable=["activitePrincipaleEtablissement", "codePostalEtablissement"],
                       pattern=[activity, territory], number=10000, closed=False)

# suppression des doublons dans la clé primaire Siret
print("Removing duplicates...")  # Message pour indiquer la suppression des doublons
export = export.drop_duplicates(subset=['siret'])

# ajout des données de localisation
print("adding location data...")
concurrents_liste = export.get_location()

print("Exporting data to CSV...")  # Message pour indiquer l'exportation des données vers le CSV
concurrents_liste.to_csv('export.csv')

print("Script finished.")  # Message pour indiquer la fin du script
```

Thank for your help

Comment: Instead of using subprocess, why can't you import the other module?

Comment: I want to create an executable UI for my colleagues who don't know how to use python

Comment: Using subprocess requires them to install python and have files in a certain directory... If you bundle apps using tools like pyinstaller / py2exe, you should use `import`'s, and never notebooks

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter should use `ipywidgets` rather than tkinter for GUI functionality... Tkinter would render desktop GUI windows, so doesn't really make sense to use a web editor for that...

In any case, you're passing in these two variables `f'--territory={territory}', f'--activity={activity}'`, but this does not automatically set them in the other script.

You need to use something like [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Also, test your command outside of jupyter, and I suspect you'll see the error that at least the territory variable is undefined

Comment: I may not have chosen the best solution... I want to create a UI for my colleagues who don't know how to use a python IDE, hence the use of tkinter to create a GUI desktop window. With Ipywidget, I have to go into the notebook, don't I?
I'll take any advice ahah.

I'm going to try your solution, thanks

Comment: You said you're already using a notebook, so yes. Otherwise, just use two py files, but that's not related to the issue here